# Nesting background property

Tags: sass

I want to nest "background" property. Can I do this in SCSS ?

```
    background:{
     #efefef;
     linear-gradient(top, $backcolor 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
     -moz-linear-gradient(top, $backcolor 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
     -webkit-linear-gradient(top, $backcolor 0%,#bbbbbb 100%);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite clear on what you mean by "nest", but i'm going to assume that means adding prefixed versions of `background: linear-gradient`. You can accomplish that with a simple mixin, or using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/):

**mixin**

```
@mixin gradient ($solid, $start, $stop) {
     background: $solid; 
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, $start 0%, $stop 100%);
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, $backcolor 0%, $stop 100%);
     background: linear-gradient(top, $start 0%, $stop 100%); 
}

body {
  @include gradient(#efefef, $backcolor, #bbbbbb);
}
```

**compass**

```
body {
  @include background(linear-gradient(top, $backcolor 0%, #bbbbbb 100%),  #efefef);
}
```

I'd highly recommend compass if you are going to be doing a lot of work in SASS.